# how to add url link to a node in graphviz on jupyter notebook

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, graphviz

From graphviz import Digraph, Graph

```
dot = Digraph(comment='First ')

dot.attr(rankdir='LR') # Left to Right

dot.node('A', 'Tax')
```

I tried to add a hyperlink to the node with label Tax using URL and href but it is not working. Could you please advise me the solution as i am a beginner in garphviz.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

According to the graphviz documentation of [`URL`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:URL) and the [python graphviz manual](http://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html), the following may work (no python user here):

```
dot = Digraph(comment='First ')
dot.attr(rankdir='LR') # Left to Right
dot.attr('node', URL='https://stackoverflow.com')
dot.node('A', 'Tax')
```

This may only be useful when choosing svg output.

Comment: @marapet..thanks for the reply but still the tax node is not acting as a hyperlink to the labelURL....there is no clickable link on the node

Comment: sorry, `labelUrl` is for edge labels, the attribute to use is `URL`. Although, depending on the viewer which is displaying the svg, hyperlinks may not work. Be sure to open the svg in a text editor and try to find the url.

Comment: I don't see any association between URL and the node. URL is assigned to a module here.

Comment: @Dims the URL is being applied to all nodes of the dot graph.

Answer (score 1):

Use href instead of URL as the parameter.

Answer (score -1):

I am using Google Colab (a Jupyter notebook server)
Nothing here seemed to work, but gave me ideas. Here is what worked for me.

```
import graphviz
from graphviz import Digraph

toc = Digraph('…', 
             engine='dot')

toc.node('Name',href="https://...")

display(toc)
```

I am still working on exporting the image